# Accessing dynamic variable value in c#.net

Tags: c#, post

Can you please tell, how can I access value of my dynamic variable in C#.NET.

```
dynamic response = api.createSession(order.Tables[0].Rows[i]["sessionid"].ToString(),
                                                            "description=" + description +
                                                            "&organization=" + organization +
                                                            "&allowUpload=" + allowUpload +
                                                            "&singleSignOnOnly=" + singleSignOnOnly +
                                                            "&maxUserCount=" + maxUserCount);
```

In above, "response" is dynamic variable and need to access its value.
I have tried following..

```
string[] myStringArray = new string[50];
myStringArray[0] = response[2]["Value"];
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you tried?  If there's a value in `response` then you can access it by using the variable `response`.  In what way is this not working for you?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, debug and inspect the response, there could be anything and nothing. Check if the response have properties, methods.

Comment: Yes, I am getting response and that is form of array list but its look like nested array list because of that I can not getting how to fetch the values..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "its value" here? Basically, the "value" of a `dynamic` variable/field is simply a reference to an object. What is *interesting* is: *what does that object provide* ? Well, we can't tell you that, because we don't know what `api.createSession` returns. But it it notionally exposed, say, an `Id` and a `Name` - then you would just use:

```
int id = response.Id;
string name = response.Name;
```

Of course, it is also possible that the object referenced by `response` exposes methods, for example:

```
response.Foo();
```

We can't tell you. And since it is `dynamic`, the *compiler* can't tell you. The only thing that can tell you is the documentation of `api.createSession`.

Comment: "api.createSession" is returning me some kind of an array having index 0,1,2 then index 2 have some another array with key and value

Comment: @Prashant again - refer to the documentation of that method

Comment: Hi, I have checked the documentation. It shows that "api.createSession" going to return XML but "api.createsession" developed in such way that it returns what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar I'm not quite sure what you want me to do here... it returns what it returns; I can't see that or play with that from here. Since it only declares `dynamic` I can't advise you on what is there. You need to ask whoever wrote that API!